# CASE в выражении ORDER BY MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, order

**Ошибка: Конфликт типов операндов: int несовместим с date**

Что я делаю не так? Хочу отсортировать по тому полю, наименование которого указано в @sortProperty.

```
DECLARE @sortProperty VARCHAR(32) = 'name'
    ,@sortDirection VARCHAR(32) =  'ASC'
    ,@start INTEGER = 5
    ,@limit INTEGER = 10;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Person;
CREATE TABLE #Person(
     surname VARCHAR(256)
    ,name    VARCHAR(256)
    ,age     INTEGER
    ,birth   DATE
) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)

INSERT INTO #Person (
    surname, name, age, birth
)
VALUES 
    ('Ivanov', 'Petr', 19, '2001-01-01'),
    ('Ivanova', 'Anna', 20, '2000-01-02'),
    ('Petrov', 'Ivan', 20, '2001-01-03'),
    ('Markov', 'Andrey', 21, '1999-01-04'),
    ('Nesterov', 'Dmitry', 22, '1998-01-05'),
    ('Sidorova', 'Irina', 25, '1995-01-06'),
    ('Zvezdina', 'Olga', 30, '1990-01-07'),
    ('Litvinov', 'Alexey', 31, '1989-01-08'),
    ('Sokolov', 'Petr', 32, '1988-01-09')
SELECT 
     prsn.surname
    ,prsn.name
    ,prsn.age
    ,prsn.birth
FROM #Person AS prsn
ORDER BY prsn.age


SELECT @sortProperty
SELECT @sortDirection

SELECT 
 prsn.surname
,prsn.name
,prsn.age
,prsn.birth
FROM #Person AS prsn
ORDER BY 
     CASE 
        WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC'
        THEN
            CASE @sortProperty
                WHEN 'surname' THEN prsn.surname
                WHEN 'name' THEN prsn.[name]
                WHEN 'birth' THEN prsn.birth
                WHEN 'age' THEN prsn.age
            END
     END ASC
    ,CASE 
        WHEN @sortDirection = 'DESC'
        THEN
            CASE @sortProperty
                WHEN 'surname' THEN prsn.surname
                WHEN 'name' THEN prsn.[name]
                WHEN 'birth' THEN prsn.birth
                WHEN 'age' THEN prsn.age
            END
    END 
    OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Преобразуй все поля к единому общему типу (видимо, строковому) в формате, который позволяет сортировать по исходному значению поля (т.е. напр. дату-время - в формат YYYYMMDDhhmmss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно правилу sql другой «тип данных» нельзя использовать в «case» для «order by». Просто разделите «случай» в зависимости от типа данных.

```
 DECLARE @sortProperty VARCHAR(32) = 'name'
        ,@sortDirection VARCHAR(32) =  'asc'
        ,@start INTEGER = 5
        ,@limit INTEGER = 10;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Person;
    CREATE TABLE #Person(
         surname VARCHAR(256)
        ,name    VARCHAR(256)
        ,age     INTEGER
        ,birth   DATE
    ) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)

    INSERT INTO #Person (
        surname, name, age, birth
    )
    VALUES 
        ('Ivanov', 'Petr', 19, '2001-01-01'),
        ('Ivanova', 'Anna', 20, '2000-01-02'),
        ('Petrov', 'Ivan', 20, '2001-01-03'),
        ('Markov', 'Andrey', 21, '1999-01-04'),
        ('Nesterov', 'Dmitry', 22, '1998-01-05'),
        ('Sidorova', 'Irina', 25, '1995-01-06'),
        ('Zvezdina', 'Olga', 30, '1990-01-07'),
        ('Litvinov', 'Alexey', 31, '1989-01-08'),
        ('Sokolov', 'Petr', 32, '1988-01-09')
    SELECT 
         prsn.surname
        ,prsn.name
        ,prsn.age
        ,prsn.birth
    FROM #Person AS prsn
    ORDER BY prsn.age


    SELECT @sortProperty
    SELECT @sortDirection


    SELECT 
     prsn.surname
    ,prsn.name
    ,prsn.age
    ,prsn.birth
    FROM #Person AS prsn
     order by 
         CASE 
           WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC' and @sortProperty in ('surname','name')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN prsn.surname
                    WHEN 'name' THEN prsn.[name]

                END            
         END ASC,
         (
          CASE 

            WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC' and @sortProperty in ('birth')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                    WHEN 'birth' THEN prsn.birth
                END
           END ) ASC,
         (
          CASE 

            WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC' and @sortProperty in ('age')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                     WHEN 'age' THEN prsn.age
                END
           END ) ASC,
           CASE 
           WHEN @sortDirection = 'DESC' and @sortProperty in ('surname','name')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                    WHEN 'surname' THEN prsn.surname
                    WHEN 'name' THEN prsn.[name]

                END            
         END desc,
         (
          CASE 

            WHEN @sortDirection = 'DESC' and @sortProperty in ('birth')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                    WHEN 'birth' THEN prsn.birth
                END
           END ) desc,
         (
          CASE 

            WHEN @sortDirection = 'DESC' and @sortProperty in ('age')
            THEN
                CASE @sortProperty
                     WHEN 'age' THEN prsn.age
                END
           END ) desc        

        OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Согласно правилу sql, другой «тип данных» не может использоваться в запросе «case» для «order by». Я просто разделил «случай» на основе типа данных.

Comment: напишите обо всём этом прямо в тексте ответа, пожалуйста.

Comment: Правильно понимаю - типы полей в одном CASE в ORDER BY должны быть одинаковыми?

Comment: да. ты прав. Проверьте мой запрос.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!!! )

Comment: Добро пожаловать :-)